# Video is not playing in Unity VideoPlayer

Tags: c#, video, unity-game-engine, server, video-streaming

Using VideoPlayer in Unity 5.6, my Nexus 5 device(Android ofc).
Loading *70mb* **4K** video from my **server**.
Facing the problem. If  **WiFi is bad**, video just *don't start to play*...
I need to make video loading smoothly and **work like on web browser**.
 If WiFi is bad, then he will **load some part and then pause** till *the other part would be loaded*.

Comment: Please, post the code you are currently using. This will help get you an answer. You may also want to tag C# or the language you are using

Comment: my URL work on my PC and not working on Android device.
`http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4` This URL working fine on my device and on PC.

Comment: You seem to have changed your question in the comment section.....The problem is that video does not play **or** video is freezing and you want it to load enough enough data before playing? I think that you should make your question clear.

Comment: Video is not playing at all.. All I can see is white screen... And I am thinking that device is stopping loading video, when WiFi is average

Comment: Remove the `videoPlayer.Prepare();` and see what happens. Also that code in your question has so many `Debug.Log` to easily troubleshoot it. Install Android Studio and use Android Monitor to see the last log from your code. That's very useful.

Comment: video is 2 sec long, but it running 0.001 sec long and ending video
**05-15 19:17:31.147 19159-19188/? I/Unity: Playing Video
                                           
                                          (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
05-15 19:17:31.148 19159-19188/? I/Unity: Done Playing Vide**

Comment: It's a bug. File for one. Help-->Report a Bug....

Comment: Without script. Using simple videoPlayer in the scene **05-15 19:30:20.455 29118-29173/? E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: Set Resolution failed
05-15 19:30:20.455 29118-29173/? E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: Setting buffer requirements (format) failed -1
05-15 19:30:20.455 29118-24730/? E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: OMX_COMPONENT_GENERATE_HARDWARE_ERROR
05-15 19:30:20.455 29118-29173/? E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: Setting buffer requirements (reqbufs) failed -1
05-15 19:30:20.455 29118-24730/? E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: ERROR: Sending OMX_ErrorHardware to Client**

Comment: Yes, it is a bug. File for a bug report and wait for Unity to fix it. The sooner you do that, the better. By the way always play video with script instead of through the component from the Editor. It let's you customize how the video is played.

Comment: Thanks. Hope, they will fix it...

Comment: @Programmer Do Unity Video player is not play the 4K resolution videos?

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan when you are using link it a buggy thing. Better to use EMT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a bug and it is still exists in unity 2017.1.
For complicated project use EMT asset.

Comment: Do Unity Video player is not play the 4K resolution videos?

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan when you are using link it a buggy thing. Better to use EMT